# Filter PrimeNG Table on Init using .ts code

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

I need to filter the table on view load.

For example, I have a table with 5 columns (`Woid`, `Customer`, `AdapterID`, `Assignee`, `Status`). On load, I want to filter `woid` column using `'contains'`. I accomplished filtering `onLoad` but when I want to filter again that column later I got an *error*:

> [i]'Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.'[/i]

Program code below...

```
@ViewChild('dt', { static: true }) dt: any;
ngOnInit() {
    this.dt.filter('22', 'woid', 'contains');
}
```

[image]

Also, after filtering via .ts code (`woid` filter) and directly in view with `<p-columnFilter>` (`customer` filter) from PrimeNG Angular collection, I get this JSON. woid property is not an array, unlike custom which is. `onFiltering` method and JSON below.

```
onFiltering(event: any) {
    console.log('Filtered value: '+ JSON.stringify(event.filters));
}


{
    "woid": {
        "value": "22",
        "matchMode": "contains"
    },
    "customer": [{
        "value": "2",
        "matchMode": "contains",
        "operator": "and"
    }]
}
```

Comment: that means ngFor getting objects, rather ngFor requres you to pass array of objects

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I see, but why is this happening after this line of code: this.dt.filter('22', 'woid', 'contains');

Comment: check the return type of data, of what type you are getting after filter `this.dt.filter`

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I think that the `woid` is a problem because `woid` doesn't contain an array of filters unlike `customer`. But I don't know why the `filter` method doesn't add a new array...

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabledynamic-demo-jat3vn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts here is demo, From my side its working fine.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I see, but the problem starts when you want to filter again directly using <p-columnFilter>. I've updated the code on stackblitz. Try to filter again and you'll get an error (Inspect->Console). https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabledynamic-demo-cnuc7e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I've found a solution. You can see it in the answer to the topic!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I replaced this line of code (in `ngAfterContentInit`):

```
this.dt.filter('22', 'woid', 'contains');
```

with this:

```
this.dt.filters['woid'] = [{value: "22", matchMode: "contains", operator: "and"}];
```

Now it works fine :)

PS. It doesn't work if you're using `stateKey` & `stateStorage`

Comment: Works fine! From where you have found out this ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda https://levelup.gitconnected.com/working-with-beautiful-primeng-data-table-filter-menu-4d318f40069e